# iptables rule to unblock internet acess, and block it again 3600 seconds later

Tags: shell-script, iptables, su, time, scheduling

I do this, from my son's terminal, to sometimes give him internet access (disabled by default):

```
./unblockinternet.sh
<enter password>
```

with this script:

```
su -c "iptables -D OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT"
```

**How to make that it automatically blocks networking again, say, 1 hour after?** (It already blocks it again for user `son` after a reboot, but I also want to block it after 3600 seconds)

More precisely, how to add a timer to do `su -c "iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT"` 3600 seconds later, without having to enter password at this time? Obviously I won't be *precisely* on his terminal 3600 seconds later exactly.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`at`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) :

```
sudo at next hour -f myiptablesscript
```

where `myiptablescript` had the command to disable access, or on one line as something like

```
sudo at next hour -f /dev/stdin <<< "iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT"
```

---

You could combine the *unblocking* and the *blocking* into a two-line script:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -D OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT
at next hour -f /dev/stdin <<< "iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT"
```

If you save this script as `unblockinternet` with execute permission, you would invoke it as

```
sudo ./unblockinternet
```

which would immediately remove the blocking rule; and queue up it's restoration to occur one hour later.

Comment: Will I have to enter the password twice when running `unblockinternet.sh` containing `su -c "iptables -D OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT"` and `sudo at next hour -f /dev/stdin <<< "iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT"`? Is there an option to have to enter it only once?

Comment: PS: If I run the script at `10:45`, will `at next hour` run at `11:45` (which is what I want) or `11:00`?

Comment: `at next hour` should run one hour from when you type it.  Or more explicitly use `at now + 1 hour`.  Presumably you would wrap both the initial _unblock_ and the `at` _block_ commands into a single script which you would run with elevated privilege (entering the password once; and adding the _block_ command to root's `at` queue; not your own).

Comment: Thanks about `+1 hour`! *you would wrap both the initial unblock and the at block commands into a single script*: for better understanding about how things are wrapped together, could you include it in the answer? Thanks in advance! I don't see clearly how the two commands should be linked?

Comment: Thanks! Last thing: user `son` is not in the "sudoers" (I don't want him to be sudoer, but I need to be able to do this command from his terminal), can I use `unblockinternet2.sh` which does "su -c "/path/to/unblockinternet.sh", and only have to type `./unblockinternet2.sh`?

Comment: @Basj That might make a good followup question to be posted separately.

Answer (score 4):

If you have systemd you could write a small Unit file, say `/etc/systemd/system/unblockinternet.service` holding

```
[Unit]
Description=unblock internet 1 hour
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/iptables ...
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 3600
ExecStop=/usr/bin/iptables ...
```

To start it enter `systemctl restart unblockinternet` and it will ask you to authenticate as root.

Comment: Great solution! And with this in `.bashrc`: `alias unblockinternet="su -c "systemctl restart unblockinternet""`, will I be able to run this with `unblockinternet` from *his* terminal (he's not sudoer)?

Comment: I had to modify it to type=simple as type=oneshot leaves the systemctl command hanging (so you would need to background it). With type=simple systemctl returns immediately, but you can only have 1 execstart, hence the use of execstartpre now.  You can also prematurely end the hour with `systemctrl stop unblockinternet`.

Comment: You can use `su` if you want, but you dont need to, nor use sudo. If you use systemctl when you are not root, it will prompt you for root's password, like su would have. It doesnt remember you did this, unlike sudo which will let you do more sudo's until some timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an ipset. This is slightly more complicated, but the timeout will be handled entirely by the kernel. One advantage is that you can renew the timeout without having to worry about canceling any queued commands.

Create the set and add corresponding iptables rules:

```
ipset create son_allowed hash:net timeout 3600
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -m set --match-set son_allowed dst -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT
```

The unblock script now only needs to add all IPs to the set:

```
ipset add son_allowed 0.0.0.0/1 -exist
ipset add son_allowed 128.0.0.0/1 -exist
```

(Note: unfortunately `0.0.0.0/0` cannot be added to an set of type hash:net, hence two entries are needed. You can also customize the timeout here by adding a `timeout SECONDS` option.)

If you use IPv6, create another ipset with flag `family inet6`, add an iptables rule for it, and in the unblock script add `::/1` and `8000::/1` to the set.